yolov5 running custom model, do I have a training problem?
I have this dataset from Roboflow and I want to train it and run it locally. I have trained it and all looks good but when I run the py script in terminal it gives me like errors.
It works when I
torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='C:/Users/user/Downloads/yolov5s.pt', force_reload=True)
but not if
torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='C:/Users/user/Downloads/best.pt', force_reload=True).
I trained the model with this ipynb. My train.py parameters were !python /content/yolov5/train.py --img 640 --batch 16 --epochs 4 --data /content/yolov5/Basketball--5/data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache.
I'm still very new to this stuff.
I was thinking that the training didn't work even though I did everything as instructed because the py script works fine with the yolov5s model, so why doesn't the best.pt work?
Local py script:
import torch
import cv2
# Model

model = torch.hub.load('Ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='C:/Users/user/Downloads/New/best.pt', force_reload=True)
#model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='C:/Users/user/Downloads/yolov5s.pt', force_reload=True)
# Images
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # 0 for default webcam

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # Read frame from webcam
    
    # Run YOLOv5 inference
    results = model(frame)
    
    # Render results
    results.render()
    
    cv2.imshow('YOLOv5 Detection', frame)
    
    # Press 'q' to exit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Terminal results:
C:\Users\user\Downloads>python run.py
Downloading: "https://github.com/Ultralytics/yolov5/zipball/master" to C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\master.zip
YOLOv5  2024-4-13 Python-3.12.3 torch-2.2.2+cpu CPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\Ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 50, in _create
    model = DetectMultiBackend(path, device=device, fuse=autoshape)  # detection model
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\Ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\common.py", line 467, in __init__
    model = attempt_load(weights if isinstance(weights, list) else w, device=device, inplace=True, fuse=fuse)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\Ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\experimental.py", line 98, in attempt_load
    ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location="cpu")  # load
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1026, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1438, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1422, in __new__
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\Ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 65, in _create
    model = attempt_load(path, device=device, fuse=False)  # arbitrary model
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\Ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\experimental.py", line 98, in attempt_load
    ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location="cpu")  # load
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1026, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1438, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1422, in __new__
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\run.py", line 5, in <module>
    model = torch.hub.load('Ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='C:/Users/user/Downloads/New/best.pt', force_reload=True)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 566, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 595, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\Ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 88, in custom
    return _create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=_verbose, device=device)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\Ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 83, in _create
    raise Exception(s) from e
Exception: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True` or see https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/pytorch_hub_model_loading for help.


"it gives me like errors" -- please post the errors and say where they are happening.

@Barbara Sorry, I forgot to clarify that the "errors" were "terminal results". it does work when i use the yolov5s.pt model but when i use my custom one it gives me the "terminal results"/"errors?"
